# Integral notation

Tags: integration, notation

I have encountered the following integral:

$\int_{x-d}^{x+d}f(y)dy$

I am trying to figure out what is the role of $d$ in this integral. Is the $d$ at the beginning of the integral the same as the $dy$? If so, why do we need to integrate from $x-d$ to $x+d$? Or is it just some other variable which has been poorly named?

Comment: You should read "$dy$" as "with respect to $y$". It has nothing to do with the variable $d$

Comment: The $d$ at the beginning is just a constant.

Comment: @drhab Thanks. So it has nothing to do with the $dy$?

Comment: If having $d$ in two places is bothersome, relabel the limits to (say) $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$.

Comment: Indeed it has nothing to do with $dy$.

Comment: The reason there is another $d$ is probably because it's an improper integral , but then it should be written as $\epsilon$, or as @Semiclassical wrote it. At least that's what I've most commonly seen, but then again it might have nothing to do with that. Go figure :D

Answer (score 1):

Some people have the habit of using non-italicized $\rm d$ before integration constant: 
$$
\int_{x-d}^{x+d}f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
I never understood why, but perhaps on this occasion this would be useful. The font emphasizes that $\mathrm{d}$ is not a variable, but a kind of operator applied to a variable (namely $y$), which is loosely described as "infinitesimal change".

Of course, one can also say that $\mathrm{d}y$ is a two-letter mathematical symbol in which the letters have no individual meaning.

And if you think this is confusing notation, wait till you come across a multiple integral over the space of matrices 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ 
like $\int\int\int\int \dots da\,db\,dc\,dd$.

Comment: As for the why, at least in some parts of the world, it is standardised. Here, we have a DIN norm mandating that it be written in non-italic font. However, when I once did that, I was told in no uncertain terms to let that be, "it is ugly, and nobody does that". While the latter is an exaggeration, the former is undeniably true.